# Kafka Streams: How to stop stream application when exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Version 1.0

Let's say in the punctuate method of lowlevel processor, creation of a dummy file fails with an exception.  How to stop the stream application when an exception is encountered?

I was wondering if there is a way to throw an exception, but could not add throw clause on the init method.  The following requires to be surrounded by a try-catch OR an exception to be thrown and can't use either one.  Please suggest.

```
Files.createFile(Paths.get(dummyFile));
```

Comment: could you be more specific how exactly file relates to kafka streams. please provide example of code

Comment: Well, it could be for any scenario, not just file. It all depends on what type of exceptions the method being used will throw.  In the above, I have specified one method "createFile" which can throw the IOException.  Now, I can catch the IOException and log an error.  But if that exception is critical and if we need the stop the streaming, how to throw the exception within the low level processor class?  I am unable to modify the Init or Process method signature to throw the Exception, if I do then it doesn't recognize as method override.

Comment: ok, so you could wrap `IOException` into any unchecked exception (like `RuntimeException`, or would be better to create your own that will extend from RuntimeException) and throw it. if your method throw exception for any incoming message, stream will be in dead state, so stop consuming messages until you restart application

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  Please post it as an answer so I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could wrap `IOException` into any unchecked exception like `RuntimeException`, or would be better to create your own that will extend from `RuntimeException`, and throw it. if your method throw exception for any incoming message, stream will be in a dead state, so stop consuming messages until you restart application